# jquery append where trigger is bigger then

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, prepend

I'm trying to append child to listing but what I want to do is to append it in the place ordering by data-price.

my template:

```
<ul>
    <li data-price="18"></li>
    <li data-price="27"></li>
    <li data-price="28"></li>
    <li data-price="31"></li>
    <li data-price="99"></li>
    <li data-price="101"></li>
    <li data-price="191"></li>
</ul>
```

my js what I've tried so far:

```
var template = '<li data-price="100"></li>';
$('ul').find('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-price") > 99;
}).after(template);
```

so if the price is 100 it should be appended by price ordering and in this case where price is greater then 99 but less then 101, but i dont have any working solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it and if it'll always work, but it works for your question. Try it out

```js
var template = '<li data-price="100">100</li>';
var checkPrice = $(template).attr("data-price");
var appendBefore = $('ul li').filter(function(){
  return parseInt($(this).attr("data-price")) > checkPrice-1;
})[0];
console.log(appendBefore);
$(appendBefore).before(template);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-price="18">18</li>
    <li data-price="27">27</li>
    <li data-price="28">28</li>
    <li data-price="31">31</li>
    <li data-price="99">99</li>
    <li data-price="101">101</li>
    <li data-price="191">191</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your answer is great but your solution works only ir the price is -1 from now. but the fact is that the lower price could be even -50 smaller

Answer (score 0):

check if that is what you need:

https://jsfiddle.net/3er0da9c/

```
var template   = '<li data-price="100"></li>';
var itemValue  = parseInt($(template).attr('data-price')); //Getting value that we should compare
var value, smaller = 0, smallerItem; //We will need those variables to know where to place our "template"


smallerItem = $('ul > li:first-of-type'); //Set the smaller item in our list to be the first one. Change that if your list wont be always asc sorted

$('ul > li').each(function(){ //run through the given list
      value = parseInt($(this).attr('data-price'));
      if ((itemValue == value) || ( itemValue > value )){ //if the actual item is equal, put our item right after it. If the item is smaller then our number, we save it and keep running
         smaller     = value;
         smallerItem = $(this);
      }
});

if (smaller != 0) //This will happens when we have at least one item smaller then our number
      smallerItem.after(template);
else
      smallerItem.before(template); //else, we add our number at top
```

Comment: @Sandra Did you test my solution? It works with negative numbers, im just curious to know if it suceed